# Name of Activity or Receiver that calls the Service

Tags: android, android-service, android-activity

I have a Intent service which is called from either a receiver or an activity. I would like to know the name of the receiver or activity that triggers the service. I don't want to use any extras or flags to pass to the service.

Is there a way to see the activity stack while the code is on the run?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way to detect sender of the Intent.

Comment: This is the right answer.  If you want, here is the official comment that this is the correct answer.  Sorry, there is no way to find this out without having the caller pass in the information for you.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to see the activity stack while the code is on the run?

You can use [ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo.html). Though it doesn't provide much API, it is probably sufficient for your requirements. Pseudocode:

```
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> runningTasks = activityManager.getRunningTasks(10);
ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo firstTask = runningTasks.get(0);
String topActivityName = firstTask.topActivity.getShortClassName();
String rootActivityName = firstTask.baseActivity.getShortClassName();
```

It gives you ability to retrieve the top and root activities of a specific task (AKA. back stack), Note that you need set persimmon [GET_TASKS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#GET_TASKS) in AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: No, please ghod, no.  This is so broken it is hard to know where to start.  Do you see anything *anywhere* saying anything about this having anything to do with telling you who sent a broadcast?  Even if you are saying no really you want to know the current foreground app when the broadcast was sent and pretend like this came from someone related to it...  you know, the user could have received a phone call right then and now you are seeing the in-call activity as the foreground.

Comment: This is the kind of stuff that results in crummy applications that break on different devices and developers then complain about Android fragmentation when it is their own darn fault.

Comment: First, every existence has their reason. This API is officially provided by Android since API Level 1, and from doc here I don't see any constrains why we can't use it in our own app. Second, like I said, it doesn't provide much useful API besides read/retrieve, I don't see any fault point caused by this simple read API you are talking about, however, where and how you are going to use the retrieved activity info is out of the scope of the question (see the first line of my answer).

Comment: You don't need to doubt what I said, I implemented and maintain the activity manager, and I know how the in-call screen works, and the problem I described exists.  Just because this API exists doesn't mean it is going to magically do what you hope it might in every situation.  This API is not in any, way, shape, or form intended to drive logic flow through an application, and definitely not when it is running in the background in a receiver.  It is for writing things like the Manage Applications UI.  It is also one I really regret having let go into the public SDK.